# Scheme Pair's help

Tags: scheme

How can you go from (5 . 2) to (5 2) ??

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Gabe: the question translates to "How do i turn a cons cell into a list?".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
(define (pair-to-list pp)
    (list (car pp) (cdr pp)))

(pair-to-list '(5 . 2))
(pair-to-list (cons 5 2))
```

Comment: well if I do (list (5 . 2)) ill get ((5 2)) and I only want (5 2)

Comment: Actually, that's not correct.  You'll get an error on (list (5 . 2)).  But if you call (pair-to-list '(5 . 2)), you'll get what you want.